# Detecting connected monitor's serial by Win32_DesktopMonitor

Tags: c#, multiple-monitors

I've been struggling an issue for a while.

I'm trying to get serial numbers of all connected monitors.

I have already tried Win32_DesktopMonitor or even CIM_DesktopMonitor with no success.

For example, I've 10 TVs connected and running (up) but those calls return only 4 of them. (see screenshot below)

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzbB1.jpg)

My best guess would be it's about WDDM but how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try another approach, for example native [EnumDisplayDevices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd162609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function. Sample code:

```
public class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var dd = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        dd.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(dd);
        uint devNum = 0;
        while (EnumDisplayDevices(null, devNum, ref dd, 0)) {
            uint devMon = 0;
            var ddMon = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
            ddMon.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(ddMon);
            while (EnumDisplayDevices(dd.DeviceName, devMon, ref ddMon, 0)) {
                Console.WriteLine(ddMon.DeviceName);
                Console.WriteLine(ddMon.DeviceID);
                Console.WriteLine(ddMon.DeviceKey);
                Console.WriteLine(ddMon.DeviceString);
                Console.WriteLine();
                devMon++;
                ddMon.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(ddMon);
            }
            devNum++;
            dd.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(dd);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(string lpDevice, uint iDevNum, ref DISPLAY_DEVICE lpDisplayDevice, uint dwFlags);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public int cb;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)] public string DeviceName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)] public string DeviceString;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)] public string DeviceID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)] public string DeviceKey;
    }

    [Flags()]
    public enum DisplayDeviceStateFlags : int {
        AttachedToDesktop = 0x1,
        MultiDriver = 0x2,
        PrimaryDevice = 0x4,
        MirroringDriver = 0x8,
        VGACompatible = 0x16,
        Removable = 0x20,
        ModesPruned = 0x8000000,
        Remote = 0x4000000,
        Disconnect = 0x2000000
    }
}
```

Read documentation of that function at link above if you got interested why it is used in such a strange way.

Comment: well, it prints out nothing... I'll try to debug.

Comment: Prints out my two monitors for me, just so that you know.

Comment: It worked on the machine that I've taken screenshot but not on my own computer. (Maybe I'm using an Apple Display from Thunderbolt output?) But the most important point is, there is no SerialNumber in DISPLAY_DEVICE struct but only DeviceID and DeviceKey which are pretty same and I guess they 're not reliable - meaning that they change when you unplug and plug them back in. I need a unique ID which does not change even if you change their connection ports.